# Pattern Count with between 0's and stat and end with "1"

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

A string  contains many patterns of the form 1(0+)1  where (0+) represents any non-empty consecutive sequence of 0's. The patterns are allowed to overlap.

For example, consider string "1101001", we can see there are two consecutive sequences "1(0)1" and "1(00)1" which are of the form 1(0+)1.

[image]

```
public class Solution {

        static int patternCount(String s){
            String[] sArray = s.split("1");
            for(String str : sArray) {
                if(Pattern.matches("[0]+", str)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int result = patternCount("1001010001");
            System.out.println(result);//3
        }
    }
```

Sample Input 
100001abc101
1001ab010abc01001
1001010001

Sample Output 
2
2
3

But still something i feel might fail in future could you pleaese help me to optimize my code as per the Requirement

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please, state clearly the expected output of the program (e.g. the number of occurences of the pattern). Apart from that, I suggest you to test it extensively: fill a file with different lines, testing every tricky aspect you can imagine. :)

Comment: This is today's question in Hackerrank's "Week of Code" competition. They do not allow to share solutions and ideas in their discussion forums. So I believe this is also against the rules?

Comment: @TedCassirer Cassirer so thats by i am asking here this is not a breaking rule this is using a network to get some good solution :)

Comment: @SadinaKhatun Rule: ...Any case of code plagiarism will disqualify... Plagiarism means: take (the work or an idea of someone else) and pass it off as one's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you did not declare the `count` variable.

Anyway, I think a better method is:

```
static int patternCount(String s){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=1)[0]+(?=1)");
    Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

You use more regex and less logic; and, for what I could see, it is even faster ([see test](http://ideone.com/OcX4pY)).

In case you didn't know, the trick used in regex is called [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). More precisely, `(?<=1)` is positive lookbehind and `(?=1)` is positive lookahead.